# Converting an old .raw video to .mp4?

Tags: video, panasonic-lumix, panasonic

I recently got an old Panasonic Lumix DMC-FZ50 from my father to use on a trip. On the trip I captured a video with the camera. When I put the video onto my laptop, I saw that the video extension is `.raw`. Is there a way for me to convert this video to `.mp4`?

Comment: video.stackexchange.com is the place to ask this (assuming it hasn't already been asked, which it probably has.)

Comment: @MichaelClark I didn't know about [video.se]. I'll direct people there in future.

Comment: Same, thanks for telling me though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) will probably do it, since it supports most video formats. It's a command-line program, but it is available for all major platforms.